# How to handle correlated variables in a dataset?

Tags: regression, linear-regression, correlation

I am wondering how to handle correlated fields in a dataset.

Some people suggest to drop this correlated fields because they don't provide any inside, other claim that a lot of information is getting lost. I am not sure if I should keep this correlated fields or not.

1. How to handle correlated data. Drop it, keep it, or does it depend on additional parameters? If yes, which? Are there rules I can follow?
2. What if the fields are sparse? (because the dataset is incomplete)
3. Does 1) depend on what kind of model is used? Regression, classification, NN?

To give a concrete example, the correlated values from the [Zillow competition](https://www.kaggle.com/c/zillow-prize-1) on Kaggle.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

If your model has dependent variables, then it's hard to interpret the coefficients down the road.

For example, say that your model has 3 variables: `profits`, `costs` and `revenue`.
You trained your linear regression model to predict `revenue` (silly, I know).

You could get the following coefficients: $c_{cost}=-1,c_{profits}=1,c_{revenue}=0$

Someone looking at these results, could conclude that `revenue` is not predictive of `revenue`.

This is kind of a trivial example because the linear dependency is very clear (`revenue=profits-costs`).

But consider it a motivation for not adding dependent variables to your model.

Correlation is a measurement of pairwise linear dependency.

It's more of a question of what type are your variables.

If your variables are continuous, Dimensionality reduction algorithms like `PCA` should account for the correlation.